# Selecting with sub queries in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two sql queries. I want to know how to combine both queries into one.

```
// query #1 - Using this query return totalpoints of specific user  ex :userId   (10234324234)
SELECT SUM(points) AS totalPoints FROM users_points WHERE user_fb_id =10234324234 AND match_id >= 2

//query #2 - Using this query will return all the records on specific condition
SELECT users_points.*, user_points.totalPoints, user.user_firstName FROM users_points INNER JOIN user ON users_points.user_fb_id = user.user_fb_id WHERE users_points.match_id >= '$matchId'
```

I want to get records, all the users records with totalPoints of each user's using one query.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: @Scuzzy i tried in few ways. but i couldn't do that. can u comment the relevant query or an example

Answer (score 0):

Just do this...

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM B WHERE my_condition = something) WHERE my_second_condition = something_else
```

If I got the order right yours should look something like this

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS totalPoints FROM (SELECT users_points.*, user_points.totalPoints, user.user_firstName FROM users_points INNER JOIN user ON users_points.user_fb_id = user.user_fb_id WHERE users_points.match_id >= '$matchId') WHERE user_fb_id =10234324234 AND match_id >= 2
```

Comment: i tried ur query directly. there was error saying need an alias. i added alias as test (SELECT SUM(points) AS totalPoints FROM (SELECT users_points.*, users_points.totalPoints, user.user_firstName FROM users_points INNER JOIN user ON users_points.user_fb_id = user.user_fb_id WHERE users_points.match_id >= 2) as test WHERE user_fb_id =10234324234 AND match_id >= 2) after running this qury i'm getting #1054 - Unknown column 'users_points.totalPoints' in 'field list'